# Jssor slider not responsive when resizing browser or viewing mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jssor

Absolutely love the Jssor slider! It works on desktop, but when viewing in mobile something goes wrong... It kind of just slides right by without being able to view the image. I am using the full width slider... I'm also realizing when I resize my browser it isn't responding on desktop either. Please help! I have reviewed the tip on making the code responsive, but that hasn't helped.

Here is my example: http://cieluxe.com/

I've been viewing on a mac with Chrome, Firefox, and my iphone 4 in safari. The iPhone is the only one I can't get to view correctly.

I have been switching the responsive code several times and haven't found an option that quite works. I already switched out the original code because I was having issues (like others had) with the slider not fitting in the container. Here is the code I have in the responsive section:

```html
 //responsive code begin
            //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
            function ScaleSlider() {
   var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
   if (parentWidth)
    jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth, 1920));
   else
    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
   }
   ScaleSlider();
   
   $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
   $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
   $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
            //responsive code end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using jquery version of jssor slider.

Please include `jquery` in your pge.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Saved me form an headache ! The only page of my website where the is not jQuery --' Ofc :)